# python external motionless library running error

Tags: python

After the installation of motionless library, I try to run my code and the following error  message occurs.

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Kevin\Downloads\tracker.py", line 4, in <module>

from motionless import CenterMap

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2222, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2164, in _find_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1940, in find_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1916, in _get_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1897, in _legacy_get_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 863, in spec_from_loader
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 904, in spec_from_file_location
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\motionless-1.1-py3.4.egg\motionless.py", 

line 55
if label and (len(label) <> 1 or not label in Marker.LABELS):
                          ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Motionless hasn't been updated since 06/08/2010 according to the [PyPi Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/motionless/1.1).

I've downloaded it and get the same error immediately just by running:

```
import motionless

print(motionless.__version__)
```

It's also not flagged as being Python 3.4 compatible in PyPi; if you are running the latest version of Python this is likely the issue.  Have you tried running it with [Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/) instead?

Edit: Looking at the Python 2.7 docs; it states [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) that `!=` and `<>` are equvilent, however `<>` is deprecated.  In the Python 3.4 docs it states [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) that only `!=` is supported, no mention of `<>` so I imagine it's been removed.

You could try instead:

- Raising an issue on the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/ryancox/motionless); the author may still be updating the library and not know it's incompatible with Python 3.4
- Checking out the code yourself from the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/ryancox/motionless) and manually fixing the problem (Check out [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) for automatically doing this.  It will convert all `<>` usage to `!=` for you)